# Resultset and CallableStatement is not closing after processing

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I am trying to close `ResultSet` and `CallableStatement` after processing but only `Connection` is closing and other two don't.

```
final String procedureCall = "{call GET_PAWS_PERSON_DETAILS(?, ?)}";
    try {

        //Get Connection instance from dataSource
        connection = dataSource.getConnection();
        callableStatement = connection.prepareCall(procedureCall);
        callableStatement.setString(1, userName);
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

        //Call Stored Procedure
        callableStatement.executeUpdate();
        // get cursor and cast it to ResultSet
        resultSet = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(2);
        logger.debug("reslt" + resultSet.getFetchSize());
        // loop it like normal
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            personDTO.setPersonID(resultSet.getString(1));
            personDTO.setFirstName(resultSet.getString(2));
            personDTO.setLastName(resultSet.getString(3));
            personDTO.setFullName(resultSet.getString(4));
            personDTO.setEmail(resultSet.getString(5));
        }

    }catch (SQLException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {
        if(resultSet != null)
            try {
                resultSet.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        if(callableStatement != null)
            try {
                callableStatement.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        if(connection != null)
            try {
                connection.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

    }
```

This code I am using. After closing just print `Connection`,`Statment` and `CallableStament`. Result is

```
Connection : null
Resultset : org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet@6f1f6b1e
Callable statement : oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper@77b1b790.
```

Because of this issue database connection pool increasing the size.

Please give me solution anyone please.

In Tomcat server.xml

```
<Resource driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" maxActive="4" maxIdle="10" maxWait="5000" name="jdbc/epaws" global="jdbc/epaws" 
        password="polusneu" type="javax.sql.DataSource" url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.60:1521:coeusnew" 
        username="polusneu" validationQuery="select 1 from dual" testOnBorrow="true" removeAbandoned="true"
  removeAbandonedTimeout="55"/>
```

applicationcontext.xml

```
<bean id="dbDataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/epaws"/>
    <property name="resourceRef" value="true"/>
    <property name="cache" value="false"/>
    <property name="lookupOnStartup" value="false"/>
    <property name="proxyInterface" value="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by them not closing, using `close` on a variable does not automatically set it to `null`...?

Comment: In my database connection pool every transaction new instance creating.Is this because of Resultset and Callable statement not closing?

Comment: I need to leave the definite answer to that question to someone with more experience with JDBC, but as long as you're not seeing exceptions when calling `close`, things look like they should be cleaned up fine with the code you're showing.

Comment: Are you calling this code repeatedly, and running out of connections?  What has made you determine that they are not getting released back to the pool?

Comment: In every transaction database instance creating.

Answer (score 0):

First off:

Closing an object will *not* set that object reference to `null`. So it's okay that you still have objects after the close. But it's strange your connection should be `null` after... but anyways.

Closing in `finally` block is valid procedure - but old-school. Java 7 introduced a terrific new feature called `try-with-resource` that takes care of closing - even in case of an error. The code would then look like

```
try(Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
    CallableStatement callable = con.prepareCall(procedureCall)) {

    callableStatement.setString(1, userName);
    callableStatement.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);

    //Call Stored Procedure
    callableStatement.executeUpdate();
    // get cursor and cast it to ResultSet
    try(ResultSet resultSet = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(2)) {
      logger.debug("reslt" + resultSet.getFetchSize());
      // loop it like normal
      while (resultSet.next()) {
          personDTO.setPersonID(resultSet.getString(1));
          personDTO.setFirstName(resultSet.getString(2));
          personDTO.setLastName(resultSet.getString(3));
          personDTO.setFullName(resultSet.getString(4));
          personDTO.setEmail(resultSet.getString(5));
      }
   } //Don't need another catch
} catch(SQLException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Sure Jan..will try.Thanks.

Comment: After connection close also database connection pool that user exists .Its didn't remove.This is causing maxconnection error.My database connection poll maxactive is 4 .So why its not removing.If know please give me a solution

Comment: closing a connection from a pool will return it to that pool. Did you check for all places where you borrow a connection from the pool? Most pools have logging for unreturned connections

Comment: Yes have checked.But when I call any transaction at that time new instance created but after transaction completed it is not removed from pool.This will cause exception.

Comment: which pool do you use? Have you activated tracing of unreturned? How did you setup your datasource?

Comment: I have added configuration on top .Iam using tomcat server.xml for setting connection pool and application context for setting jndi datasource and every class have called datasource.

Comment: @Jan, you are correct, AutoCloseable feature supported from JDK 1.7 closes all resources automatically.  It should be used whereever possible.

Try reducing the MaxWait from 5000 to a smaller value and see if releases the connection.  Also, try setting some timeout properties too to clean up connections. 

Also, you can use Universal Connection Pool (UCP) which is a Java connection pool.  Refer to "UCP withTomcat" (www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/planned-unplanned-rlb-ucp-tomcat-2265175.pdf)  whitepaper for more details on its configuration in Tomcat.